# IIS Server HTML file fallback

Tags: iis

We have a folder where our Static HTML files are stored and a server that can also render web pages.

Our desire is when a user visists a page like http://example.com/trend/phones/ then IIS checks first if the HTML file exists in example.com/trend/phones/index.html and if it exists then that particular HTML file will be served. However if it does not exist then it must proxy to the server instead so it will avoid 403 or 404 messages

Below is my rule so far but it returns 500

```
<rule name=“403And404FallBack">
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Please ensure the you have specified default document index.html for your folder trend/phones/.

2.Please ensure ARR has been installed and forward proxy has been enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing

3.Please enure http://localhost:3000 can be accessed from your IIS server

```
  <rule name="rewrite rule">
                    <match url="(.*)\/$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: ARR is installed yes. I will try this solution of yours